# while loop to stop until a variable reaches between two numbers

Tags: while-loop

lets say I have a variable x that starts at 90  and I want a loop that will decrease x until it reaches two numbers lets say

```
while(when x is between 50 and 55 stop the loop)
 {
   x = x-3;
 {
```

Comment: What language are you coding in exactly...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
while( ! (x>50 && x<55)) {
   x = x-3;
}
```

A `for` loop might actually be easier:

```
for (x=90; x=x-3; (x>55||x<50)) {
  // do something
}
```

The exact possibilities and code obviously depend one the language used...

But take care: what if your decrement leaves x with a value *lower* than 50? Do you really need that lower border when you are monotonously decreasing the value of x?